# Call function with Ajax on ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

```
   public ActionResult CheckNumber(string number) {
            if (List !=0) {
                return View("Index");
            }
            else {
                return View("False");
                    }
        }
```

I have a `CheckNumber` method like above. I want to write an Ajax on view to call this method. If `if (List !=0)` will call `Index()` method. How can I do that?

My `Index()` method:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index(tempUser userDetails) {}
```

Comment: I think you should return a bool and based on that you should use onsuccess

Answer (score 2):

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: '/controller/CheckNumber',
    data: {number},
    success: fucntion(result){
        if(result.redirect === 'Index'){
            location.replace('/controller/Index')
        }
    }
})
```

And in controller u need to pass obj like this

```
if (List !=0) {
     return Json(new {redirect = true}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
}
```

Of course u can modify this code to work how u want to, but this is example how to use Ajax call

Comment: And change `controller` to actual name of your controller, I don't have that info from your example

Answer (score 2):

I like Serlok's method. I use a similar approach on projects quite often. I don't use it to redirect pages, but I send responses back often for various alerts. I just prefer since I've already sent the request to the server, why send a response back to the calling ajax method? Just redirect to another view right there.

This way is just a different alternative. You use the controller to RedirectYourAction. Another controller, which will fire your view.  This way has worked well for me

```
    var data = JSON.stringify({ 'number': userInput});

   $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: '/controller/CheckNumber',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: data,
        success: function(response){
          console.log(response);
          //You could do your redirect here. 
       }
      }
    })


      public ActionResult CheckNumber(string number)
    {
        int List = Convert.ToInt32(number);
        if (List != 0) //You have List here, you sure you don't mean number? Or you're instantiating a list somewhere..
        {
            RedirectToAction("Index"); //Takes you to your index controller and the view associated with it. Same as below. 
        }
        else
        {
            RedirectToAction("SomeOtherControllerName");
        }
        return View();//default controller view.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bottom link , it's a article for some easy example about your issue.

[enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4)